# autocomplete trazer informações para 2 campos diferentes

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery

O problema que estou passando se deve ao fato de estar precisando retornar 2 valores distintos para campos diferentes, a partir de um autocomplete que esta funcionando no campo "produto".

Ele busca via sql e retorna o nome do produto já, agora quero que o valor da coluna quantidade no banco de dados também preencha o campo estoque na tabela.

Estou perdido nisso, se alguém puder me ajudar agradeço !!

HTML

> ```
> `<input type="text" name="produto" class="produto' + contador + '" />`
> `<input type="text" name="estoque' + contador + '" />`
> ```

JS

> ```
> $(".produto").autocomplete({
> source: "../../../sistema/PDV/assets/php/busca_produtos.php",
> minLength: 2,
>
>       select: function(event, ui){
>
>       //event.preventDefault();
>
>       var1 = ui.item.produto_id +' - '+ ui.item.produto_nome ;
>
>       $('input[name="produto' + contador + '"]').val( var1 ),
>       $('input[name="estoque' + contador + '"]').val (ui.item.produto_qtd )
>
>       }
>
> });
> ```

PHP

> ```
> if (isset($_GET['term'])){
>
> $return_arr = array();
>
> try {
>     $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=".DB_SERVER.";dbname=".DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
>     $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
>
>     $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT id,nome,quantidade FROM produtos WHERE nome LIKE :term ");
>     $stmt->execute(array('term' => '%'.$_GET['term'].'%'));
>
>     while($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
>
>         // $return_arr[] =  $row['id'].' - '.$row['nome'].' - '.$row['quantidade'] ;
>
>        $return_arr[] =  array(
>
>            'value' => $row['nome'], //Valor para referência na interface
>
>
>            'produto_id'    => $row['id'],
>            'produto_nome'  => $row['nome'],
>            'produto_qtd'   => $row['quantidade']
>        );
>
> } catch(PDOException $e) {
>     echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
> }
>
>
> echo json_encode($return_arr); 
>
> }
> ```

Após correções no código com ajuda do @Wilson consegui exibir as informações porem existe um contador no grid dinâmico onde eu referencio cada linha e item por ele. E quando add 2 ou mais linhas o resultado sempre aparece no ultimo item criado, se for possível ajustar esta falha seria de grande ajuda ... Obrigado desde já !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thiago, primeiro precisamos alterar o seu resultado em PHP para retornar um objeto JSON a partir de um array, assim:

**PHP**

```
while(...){
    $return_arr[] =  array(
        'value' => $row['nome'], //Valor para referência na interface
        'produto_id' => $row['id'],
        'produto_nome' => $row['nome'],
        'produto_qtd' => $row['quantidade'],
    );
}

echo json_encode($return_arr);
```

Após isso, temos que definir um *callback* para a o evento `select`, que é o evento disparado quando o usuário seleciona um item da lista. Note que podemos acessar o valor enviado pelo JSON do php pelo objeto `ui.item`. Deste modo, podemos alterar o valor do parâmetro `value` dos `input`, fica deste modo:

**JS**

```js
$(".produto").autocomplete({
    source: "../../../sistema/PDV/assets/php/busca_produtos.php",
    minLength: 2,
    select: function(event, ui){
        event.preventDefault();
        $('input[name="produto"]').val(ui.item.produto_id),
        $('input[name="estoque"]').val(ui.item.produto_qtd)
    }
});
```

Referência: https://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-select

Comment: Até funcionou da forma que preciso, porem não esta exibindo o val() no campo produto, a busca fica tudo em branco e quando seleciono continua em branco, o estoque apareceu legal.

o que pode ser feito pra corrigir isso, pois quando dou um console.log esta exibindo os valores certos !

Comment: Testei aqui adicionando `event.preventDefault();` no início da function do select. Editei a resposta. No meu teste funcionou aqui.

Comment: não exibe na busca ainda, mas quando seleciono retorna o valor sim. Melhorou mas não esta como tem de ficar, o que esta atrapalhando a exibição da busca

Comment: Faz o seguinte, vamos colocar o campo `value` no PHP. Acho que o jquery fica perdido sem esse campo! Editei a resposta. PS: caso queira voltar o valor da busca pro campo de produto tira o `event.preventDefault();`

Comment: Sensacional amigo, funcionou bem demais obrigado !! Se possível agora vou pedir um apoio na sequencia para o código ficar perfeito.

Comment: Thiago, se resolveu seu problema, marque a resposta como solução. Para outro problema sugiro vc abrir outro tópico no Stack!

Comment: Ok, obrigado jovem tenhau m otimo dia !!